# How to decrypt SQL passwords?

Tags: mysql

I add encryped password using this command:

```
insert into users values ("new@emal.com",ENCRYPT("password"));
```

Now I have encrypted passwords in that table. Is it possible to decrypt them and if yes how? What kind of algorithm is this?

Somebody hacked something on my server and is sending mails. It looks like that the password of some old accounts was guessed. So I am trying to find out what password I had there (just changed it). So I can see what password I should stop using.

Comment: syntax error in the command.

Comment: No, not corrected. You need single quotes to delimit text strings in queries, not double quotes.

Comment: In my works fine like this. Not sure if it is because it is mariadb or because of some coding in my machine, but it works with double quotes

Comment: @OllieJones "A string is a sequence of bytes or characters, enclosed within either single quote (“'”) or double quote (“"”) characters." - [MySQL docs - String Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html). Since MariaDB is basically MySQL, it shouldn't have issues with double-quoted strings as well.

Answer (score 1):

The [`ENCRYPT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_encrypt) function doesn't work on MySQL running on Windows.

On Unix-style servers it uses the [crypt(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) function. This performs a one-way encryption of the text you pass it.

This is not, repeat not, a secure way to store user passwords any more. If you use this on a network-accessible web site, a cybercriminal is almost certain to pwn your users. Please read this for advice:  http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. Somebody hacked something on my server and is sending mails. It looks like that the password of some old accounts was guessed. So I am trying to find out what password I had there (just changed it). So I can see what password I should stop using.

Comment: The only common way to encrypt postfix & dovecot together is this way. This is the only common way for both of them is ENCRYPT